# create string pairs from list - tea anyone?

Tags: c#, string

In our company we have x number of people. We want to generate a roulette - tea break app in C# to run, where those who subscribe to this function, will have their names added to a list on a text file.

Then we want to "spin the wheel" (click a button...) which generates pairs from this name list, who will then schedule a tea break together.

Sample List (loaded from text file):

1. Peter
2. Mary
3. Joan
4. James
5. Dean
6. Laura

Once we click the button to Spin the Wheel
we need to:

Generate a new list of paired names eg:

- Mary will have tea with James
- Dean will have tea with Peter
- Joan will have tea with Laura

I am trying to figure out how to code this.
Conditions:
The output of this month's spin is stored into another text file, whereby James had tea with Mary this month, and will not be having tea with Mary again for at least 6 months.
 Sample Text file - Appended each month:

```
* 01MAY2015,2,4
* 01MAY2015,5,1
* 01MAY2015,3,6
* etc...
```

The final output list item count will be half of the number of items in the main list.  So you will not see any name have tea with more than one person for each time the wheel spins.

Next Month we will check the previous months output lists to make sure the names are not paired with each other again.

Has anyone done something like this before?

My Pairmatching code is as follows:

In the Click Event of the "Spin" button:

```
List<string> q = new List<string>(Variables.gsNames); //I load the names into a global variable list 
List<string> pairs = new List<string>(Variables.gsNames.Length * (Variables.gsNames.Length - 1)); // I load the pairs into another global var list

while (q.Count > 0)
{
    string n1 = q[0];
    q.RemoveAt(0); // name1 was next in line

    // try to pair with the first in line who have not been paired with this name before
    foreach (string n2 in q)
    {
        // create a normalized "candidate" pair with the next name in line
        string p = string.Compare(n1, n2) < 0 ? n1 + " and " + n2 : n2 + " and " + n1;

        if (!pairs.Contains(p))
        {
            // the two staffmembers have not been paired before
            pairs.Add(p);
            q.Remove(n2);
            q.Add(n1);
            q.Add(n2);
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(p);
            lvPairs.Items.Add(lvi);
            // the pair is recorded and the names have been moved to the end of the line
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help or guidance for this.
Thank you in advance for your help.
Len

Comment: Doesn't it make sense to create a unique List for 6 months at once?

Comment: For a start you need to seperate this out. Write a method that takes `List<string>` and returns `List<TeaParty>` where `TeaParty` is an object with two string properties. You're mixing this in with the view (and how to generate the strings `"{0} will have tea with {1}"`), don't do that.

Comment: What is the exact problem you experience with this code? I'd suggest moving this question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you Nathan. I can take it under review and see if this is plausible.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something like this:

```
var matches = new List<TeaParty>();
var people  = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Peter" },
    new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Mary"  },
    new Person { Id = 3, Name = "Joan"  },
    new Person { Id = 4, Name = "James" },
    new Person { Id = 5, Name = "Dean"  },
    new Person { Id = 6, Name = "Laura" },
};
```

My idea is to work with a person at time and look if he/she isn't violation any given rules:

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2016, 01, 01);
foreach (var iteration in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
{
    var thisMonth = startDate.AddMonths(iteration);
    foreach (var person in people)
    {
        var invitee = people.FirstOrDefault(potential =>

            // can't have tea alone
            potential.Id != person.Id &&                        

            !matches.Any(previous =>

                // can't party more than once per month
                (previous.Date == thisMonth && previous.Contains(person, potential)) ||

                // can't have tea with same person within 6 months
                (previous.Date >= thisMonth.AddMonths(-6) &&  
                (
                    previous.Contains(person) && previous.Contains(potential)
                ))));

        if (invitee != null)
        {
            var party = new TeaParty(thisMonth, person, invitee);
            matches.Add(party);
            Console.WriteLine(party);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to process the matches for the next month");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

However, this program fails after the first interaction:

```
Month #1
Peter will have tea with Mary
Joan will have tea with James
Dean will have tea with Laura

Month #2
Peter will have tea with Joan
Mary will have tea with James
```

Where is Dean?

As Peter and Mary exchanged partners among them, Dean is left to take tea again with Laura, and that's forbidden by the rules.

If somebody want to continue from this point, here follows the rest of the code:

```
class Person
{
    public int    Id    { get; set; }
    public string Name  { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}

class TeaParty
{
    public DateTime Date  { get; set; }
    public Person Inviter { get; set; }
    public Person Invitee { get; set; }

    public TeaParty() { }
    public TeaParty(DateTime date, Person inviter, Person invitee) : this()
    {
        this.Date = date;
        this.Inviter = inviter;
        this.Invitee = invitee;
    }

    public bool Contains(params Person[] guests)
    {
        return guests != null && guests
            .Any(guest => this.Inviter.Id == guest.Id || this.Invitee.Id == guest.Id);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} will have tea with {1} at {2:D}", 
            this.Inviter, this.Invitee, this.Date);
    }
}
```